# How can I calculate the rotation angle for a div element?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to make a `div` face towards an `x` and `y` position on the screen.

For example, if I have a `div` at coordinates `50, 0`, and I want it to face `0, 0`, then I would need to rotate the div `-90` degrees (or left).

Is there some sort of equation or function I can use to get the degrees that the `div` should rotate, depending on the two sets of coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript:

```
Math.atan2(dx, dy) * 180 / Math.PI
```

Where

```
dx = p2.x - p1.x 
dy = p2.y - p1.y
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I really have no idea what happened here or why dx and dy seem to be replaced while atan2 accepts y and x as parameters, but I added Math.PI and subtracted the result of Math.atan2 calculated by the way of this code snippet, and then it worked for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rotate` method to achieve the rotation of an element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div#myDiv {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The rotate() Method</h1>
<p>The rotate() method rotates an element clockwise or counter-clockwise.</p>

<div>
This a normal div element.
</div>

<div id="myDiv">
This div element is rotated clockwise -90 degrees.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/1763/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know how to rotate the element, I'm looking for a way to get the amount it should rotate depending on the two sets of coordinates.